# Download Image CORS issue s3

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js, cors

I'm having a problem in downlading image from s3. It was working the other day but right now it got CORS Error. Also, I am using Next.js v12.3.0 and Strapi

Here is the CORS Config: *( just imagine that I added the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `ExposeHeaders` )*

[image]

I update the CORS Configuration and added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `ExposeHeaders` and it works it downloaded the image successfully, no CORS Error. However, just yesterday up until now CORS Error is back and I don't know why it's not working again.

This is the new error appeared[image]

Here is the code on how I handle download image

```
export const downloadURI = async (imageUrl, name) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(imageUrl);
    const blob = await response.blob();

    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    a.download = name;

    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();

    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    document.body.removeChild(a);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error downloading image:', error);
  }
};
```

**UPDATE**: The bucket is not accessible in public. I think that's why it got CORS error

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is part of the problem. But if you are using the `@strapi/provider-upload-aws-s3` you also need to update the `middlewares.js`  file.

```js
// ~/strapi-aws-s3/backend/config/middlewares.js
    
    module.exports = [
      'strapi::errors',
      /* Replace 'strapi::security', with this snippet */
      /* Beginning of snippet */
      {
        name: 'strapi::security',
        config: {
          contentSecurityPolicy: {
            useDefaults: true,
            directives: {
              'connect-src': ["'self'", 'https:'],
              'img-src': [
                "'self'",
                'data:',
                'blob:',
                'dl.airtable.com',
                'yourBucketName.s3.yourRegion.amazonaws.com',
              ],
              'media-src': [
                "'self'",
                'data:',
                'blob:',
                'dl.airtable.com',
                'yourBucketName.s3.yourRegion.amazonaws.com',
              ],
              upgradeInsecureRequests: null,
            },
          },
        },
      },
      /* End of snippet */
      'strapi::cors',
      'strapi::poweredBy',
      'strapi::logger',
      'strapi::query',
      'strapi::body',
      'strapi::session',
      'strapi::favicon',
      'strapi::public',
    ];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, we have same config but still got cors error

Comment: Thats sucks.  I was reading this article https://www.propelauth.com/post/avoiding-cors-issues-in-react-next-js not sure if it will have any tips that you haven't tried.  But I am going to try to replicate the issue on my free time.  Where or how are you deploying Strapi?

Comment: The bucket is not accessible in public. I think that's why it got CORS error but the current host is whitelisted in the cors config. I don't know why it's not accepting it. Do you think I should use `aws-sdk` in nextjs api route?